# Electromagnetism - DC Motor Design Question - EMF/BACK EMF

Tags: motors, electromagnetism

I'm not gonna lie - I don't have enough knowledge about EMF and Back EMF so I need you guys , my friend will soon build a DC motor for me but I currently have no idea what design will produce high speeds (~5000RPM) and high torque {at low speeds ofcourse} (~100nm) .

I'm not limited by power consumption but I'm worried about cooling design and cooling performance so I prefer using thick wires which will stay cool during operation under high currents .

My problem is - thick wires have low resistance , hence - I'll need to supply very low voltage (1V-3V , when 300A is used , which is 300J of energy) , I want to use those wires as coils in the stator and want them to act like the North and South poles magnets as designed in a brushed DC motor but I am worried about back emf because I need the motor to reach high speeds .

So my question is : if I am operating this thick stator coils with the low voltages I said earlier , will the rotor coils easily cancel out the stator's EMF so the motor reach only low speeds ? and if they will easily produce back emf which will suppress the stator's EMF and limit the motor speed to a very low speed - can I fix this issue using a high voltage low current coils wrapped around the low voltage high current coils and that will cancel the back emf coming from the rotor so I can reach high speeds ?

I know I don't know basic EMF concepts , sorry guys for my stupidity...

Comment: This is wrong. That is 300J/s aka 300W. "high speeds (~5000RPM) and high torque {at low speeds ofcourse} (~100nm)" You don't. That's why transmissions exist. You need to re-evaluate your specifications because they are unreasonable with modern technology and materials. If you get it to run slowly at high torque then at high speed it will be too heavy and tear itself apart or blow the winding insulation from overvoltage. I think high frequency eddies can also demagnetize. But if you make it able to run at high speed it will cook at low RPM.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks , that was really helpful !